# Exec format error: Unable to run appimage files on ubutu 16.04 and lubuntu 18

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, lubuntu, appimage

I've been trying to run Qv2ray and other programs on Ubuntu 16.04 and Lubuntu 18, but I always get this error:

```
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.
```

Here's [the article that I've read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it) in order to run appimage files:

I tried these steps:

1. Installing fuse: sudo apt install libfuse2
2. Making the file executable in properties(Checked).
3. Double clicking on the file.

Another file with a weird name appeared next to it, but the program was not executed, and also when I try to run it I get this error:

```
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use snap to install `qv2ray`:

```
sudo snap install qv2ray
```

You get an error, probably because `qv2ray` require at least Ubuntu 20.04.

[Supported Distributions](https://github.com/Qv2ray/debian?tab=readme-ov-file#supported-distributions).

[Snapcraft: qv2ray](https://snapcraft.io/install/qv2ray/ubuntu)

Comment: but my laptop is 32bit and I can't install other versions of ubuntu on it...